# IIS website paths behave different when accessing the site from outside the network

Tags: asp.net, iis

As the title states, I get different behavior on my website when I try to access it from the internet, as opposed to accessing it from the local network, and I cannot figure out why. I know it is because IIS is trying to serve me content from the parent application, but I don't know how to fix it.

Let me try explain: I have a website (not a web application) that I deployed to an existing IIS site, and then converted it to an application. If I access the website from the local network (`<hostname>/path/to/site.aspx`) then everything works fine, but when I try to access the site from the internet (`<domain.name>/path/to/site.aspx`) then it breaks, and I have the mappings set up correctly for the domain (it works on the parent application).

Initially it couldn't access the Site.Master page, saying the file cannot be found at `<Site Parent Folder>/Site.Master` (Instead of `<Site Parent Folder>/<Current App>/Site.Master`), so I had to change the master page reference on the ASP page from `~/Site.Master` to just `Site.Master` And that seems to have worked for the master page only. It now gives me an error about being unable to find my classes in the `App_Code` directory (`The type or namespace name 'MyClass' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`) so I'm suspecting that it is still trying to reference those from the parent directory.
Any ideas on how I can fix it so that it references the current application's directory instead of the parent app's directory?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your deployed website is running as a sub-applicaiton under main IIS site.

In your main IIS website update web.config and wrap `system.web` section with location element with `inheritInChildApplications` set to false

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false"> 
    <system.web> 
    … 
    </system.web> 
  </location>
```

You can read more about it [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ChangingASPNETWebconfigInheritanceWhenMixingVersionsOfChildApplications.aspx)